# how to pick key and value from a dictionary and build a new dictrionary

Tags: python-2.7

i have a dic like this: {'a=1','b=2','c=3','d=4','e=5'}
now how to randomly pick some pairs of keys and value to build a new dic?
I hope the new dic is gonna be like this: {'c=3','b=2'}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
import random

x = 2 # Amount of Random choices
dict = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4, 'e':5} 
dict2 = {}

for _ in range(x):
    key = random.choice(list(dict.keys()))  # Chose a random key
    dict2[key] = dict[key] # Add it to new dict
    dict.pop(key, None) # Remove from old dict, so it doesn't get picked again

print(dict2)
```

Comment: Thank you for this! That is helping. By the way, what is that mean in your code that dict2[key] = dict[key] # Add it to new dict  why use [] and why key is inside the [].

Comment: Using that syntax tells python to add a new value, with the key being `key` to the dictionary.